# How to let a function [a] -> [a] operate on [(a,Int)]?

Tags: haskell, abstraction

I find myself often writing code following the pattern:

```
foo xs = map snd $ filter ((< 10).fst) $ zip xs [0..]

bar ys = map snd $ sortBy (compare `on` fst) $ zip ys [0..]
```

Now I want to abstract this away

```
foo = indexesOf (filter (<10))

bar = indexesOf sort

indexesOf :: ([a] -> [a]) -> [a] -> [Int] 
indexesOf f xs = map snd $ magick $ zip xs [0..] where
    magick = undefined
```

How to perform the `magick`?

Comment: ...I'm really not clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: I have a function working on a list, say `sort`. Now instead of the sorted list I want to get back the *indexes* of the elements. E.g. for `[5.0, 8.0, 7.0]` I don't want `[5.0. 7.0, 8.0]` but `[0,2,1]`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your type signature won't work. You need to be able to give the passed function a list of tuples, which means that you either have to use higher-rank types to force it to be polymorphic, or explicitly mention tuples in your type signature.

Without this, you can't "look inside" the function to see how it rearranges the elements of the list. In fact, given your type signature the passed function could do anything it wanted to the list, including inserting elements that weren't even in there to begin with!

Here's what I got to work using higher-rank types:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}

import Data.List (sortBy)
import Data.Ord (comparing)

indexesOf :: (forall b. (b -> a) -> [b] -> [b]) -> [a] -> [Int]
indexesOf f xs = map snd $ f fst $ zip xs [0..]

foo :: (Ord a, Num a) => [a] -> [Int]
foo = indexesOf (filter . ((< 10) .))

bar :: Ord a => [a] -> [Int]
bar = indexesOf (sortBy . comparing)
```

Note that I also had to add an extra argument to the passed function to tell it how to extract the part it cares about from the elements of the list it's working on. Without this, you would only be able to use functions that don't inspect the elements of the list, such as `reverse`, and that wouldn't be very useful.

**Example run in GHCi:**

```
> let xs = [42, 0, 7, 3, 12, 17, 99, 36, 8]
> foo xs
[1,2,3,8]
> bar xs
[1,3,2,8,4,5,7,0,6]
> indexesOf (const reverse) xs
[8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0]
```

Comment: I think you're answering the question in the title.

Comment: (continuing) ... but in the given examples the function is actually `:: (Ord a) => [a] -> [a]`. So you can "look inside".

Comment: @RafaelCaetano: You still need to be able to pick a different `a`, either through a higher-rank type or by explicitly mentioning tuples in the type signature. You _could_ make the type signature `indexOf :: (forall b. Ord b => [b] -> [b]) -> [a] -> [Int]`, however that would only work for the `sort` example, and not the one with `filter`, since the function would only be able to compare elements with eachother. It would not be able to compare against `10`.

Comment: I think the signature `indexesOf :: (forall b . [(a,b)] -> [(a,b)]) -> [a] -> [Int]` on top of mnish's implementation is simpler to understand and equally well-behaved. Users have to write `fst` explicitly instead of delaying composition, so this is less higher-order, slightly more redundant, and easier to use. Your type would make more sense if we had a collection of functions reusing this concept of `reordering from projection`.

Comment: @gasche: Good observation, although you would have to write `fst` in exactly the same places as you would have to type `f` in `indexesOf (\f -> ...)`, so the difference is not that great.

Answer (score 4):

Great question, but I suspect there exists no such function.
See [Theorems For Free!](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/wadler/papers/free/free.ps). 
Like hammer says, you need to pass functions that take tuples explicitly.

Here is my slightly simplified version that doesn't require RankNTypes (which is, admittedly, not a very good improvement over the original code):

```
import Data.List
import Data.Ord

indexesOf :: ([(a,Int)] -> [(a,Int)]) -> [a] -> [Int]
indexesOf f xs = map snd $ f $ zip xs [0..]

foo :: (Ord a,Num a) => [a] -> [Int]
foo = indexesOf $ filter $ (< 10) . fst

bar :: Ord a => [a] -> [Int]
bar = indexesOf $ sortBy $ comparing fst
```

Comment: This is correct, although higher-rank types give you slightly stronger guarantees since the function can't mess with the integers. All it can do is reorder, copy and remove the existing items in the list.

Comment: That's true. Also, when one has a function of type a -> Int, it must be trivial, that is, a constant (or undefined).