# Is it possible to implement this function?

Tags: list, function, haskell

I want to have a function `q` of type:

```
q :: ([b] -> b) -> ([(a, b)] -> (a, b))
```

which takes a function that selects a single element from a list, and lifts* that function into the context of selecting a single pair from a pair of lists (completely ignoring the first element of the pairs).

Is it even possible to write such a function?  I haven't been able to make any progress on this.

<sub>*is 'lift' the right word?</sub>

---

Example use:  if I have a function:

```
safeMaximum :: b -> [b] -> b

> safeMaximum 18 [] 
18
> safeMaximum 18 [4,5,1,4,3]
5
```

I then want to use `safeMaximum` to get, from a list of pairs, the pair whose 2nd element is the largest:

```
liftedSafeMaximum :: (a, b) -> [(a, b)] -> (a, b)
liftedSafeMaximum val = q val safeMaximum

liftedSafeMaximum ("?", 3) []
> ("?", 3)
liftedSafeMaximum ("?", 3) [("xyz", 1), ("123", 3), ("hi", 2)]
> ("123", 3)
```

Comment: I'd guess you can't, since, if the `[(a, b)]` list is empty, you'd need to make an `a` out of thin air.  You could write `q :: ([b] -> b) -> ([(a, b)] -> Maybe (a, b))`, though.

Comment: @scvalex Or you can not terminate. `undefined` etc. are ugly and a bad idea, but legal.

Comment: Good point, but I need a function that actually works.

Comment: @scvalex you're right, but even if I change the signature to `q :: (a, b) -> ([b] -> b) -> ([(a, b)] -> (a, b))` I'm still stuck.

Comment: Sure: `let q pair _ _ = pair`

Comment: With the new signature, you can of course write the trivial `q pair _ = \_ -> pair`.

Comment: @DanielFischer good point; I should have clarified that I'm not looking just to satisfy the type, but to lift a function into a new context.  I've updated the OP.

Comment: @pelotom good point; I should have clarified that I'm not looking just to satisfy the type, but to lift a function into a new context. I've updated the OP.

Comment: With the updated type, I don't think it's possible because you can't correlate the `b`s with the `a`s.  I.e. you can fold the `b`s, but you have no idea which `a` the resulting `b`, if any, was next to.

Comment: This looks similar in spirit to [How to let a function `[a] -> [a]` operate on `[(a,Int)]`?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9324862/how-to-let-a-function-a-a-operate-on-a-int/9325094)

Comment: I've rolled back since all the answers refer to that previous version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You describe this as wanting to "lift a function into a context", so let's see what that works out to mean. Starting from the desired type:

```
q :: (a, b) -> ([b] -> b) -> ([(a, b)] -> (a, b))
```

...we can optimistically abstract over the desired context:

```
q :: f b -> ([b] -> b) -> ([f b] -> f b)
```

Assuming that `f` is a `Functor`--which it is, in the motivating example--we could lift `[b] -> b` to `f [b] -> f b`. We could get from that to the desired type if we had a function of type `[f b] -> f [b]`, which looks a lot like `sequence`.

Consider the case where `f` is `((->) a)` instead: given a function `[b] -> b` and a list `[a -> b]`, we can return a function `a -> b` that applies its argument of type `a` to every function in the list, uses the selector function, then returns the result of type `b`. That sounds like what you're after!

Unfortunately it doesn't work for your specific example--the `Monad` involved is the writer monad, which would add a `Monoid` constraint on `a` and always return the monoid sum of every `a` value in the list.

The reason it fails is that we have only an opaque selection function for `b` values, which by necessity must be used without any context, which entails using something like `sequence` to extract (and in the process merge) all the individual contexts. To write the function you want, you'd need a way to merge contexts without losing information associating a context to each element.

The reader monad works where others don't because the "merge" process involved is unique--applying a single argument to multiple functions is based on a contravariant use of the canonical comonoid given by `\x -> ()` and `\x -> (x, x)`, where each result element uniquely determines the original input.

To get the same property in covariant position, we would need a monoid where each input element uniquely determines the resulting sum, which implies that every input must be the same, which implies that they must be of a type with only one value. Based on that, we can indeed write a version of your function with a slightly more restricted type:

```
q' :: ([b] -> b) -> ([((), b)] -> ((), b))
```

But I suppose that's not very satisfying. :]

Answer (score 4):

You can get something like this to work if you're willing to refine your definition of a selector function slightly. Instead of selecting an element from a list directly, we will have a polymorphic function that, given a projection that allows it to look at the part of each element it's interested in, will select an item from a list.

All `q` has to do then, is give it `snd` as the projection to use.

```
{-# LANGUAGE Rank2Types #-}

import Data.Ord (comparing)
import Data.List (maximumBy)

q :: (forall c. (c -> b) -> c -> [c] -> c) -> (a, b) -> [(a, b)] -> (a, b)
q select = select snd

safeMaximumOn :: Ord b => (a -> b) -> a -> [a] -> a
safeMaximumOn proj x xs = maximumBy (comparing proj) (x:xs)

liftedSafeMaximum :: Ord b => (a, b) -> [(a, b)] -> (a, b)
liftedSafeMaximum = q safeMaximumOn
```

This is essentially the same idea from [a previous answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9324862/how-to-let-a-function-a-a-operate-on-a-int/9325094#9325094).

Comment: @WillNess: I agree there's probably not much practical use for this :) Which pattern match failure? The list I'm passing to `maximumBy` is non-empty.

Comment: You could always handle the empty case differently. That's not important here. Besides, that example won't typecheck. Parametricity guarantees that the passed function must pick one of the elements from the list, so something like `sum` won't work at all.

Answer (score 2):

Isn't this trivial now, with the new signature/interface?

```
import Data.List (elemIndex)

q v f [] = v
q v f xs = let ys = map snd xs; x = f (snd v) ys in
           case elemIndex x ys of Just i -> xs !! i ; _ -> v 
                                               -- or (fst v, x) if you prefer
```

There can be no `safeMaximum` without the `Ord` constraint, right? So was that an omission, or by design?

Comment: `b` doesn't have an `Eq` instance in the original type, so you can't compare them for equality.

Comment: @scvalex is this by design or by omission? the OP says "I have a function `safeMaximum`"... without `Eq` how there can be a function searching for maximum? Without the Eq constraint for `safeMaximum` there's a contradiction in the question.

Comment: @scvalex that is, Ord is needed for finding maximum, and Ord implies Eq... Right?

Comment: @WillNess You're right.  Other than traversing the list twice, I think your solution seems fine.

Comment: hmm ... `*> q (1,2) (\_ y -> sum y) (liftM2 (,) [1..3] [1..4])
*** Exception: Select.hs:11:51-71: Irrefutable pattern failed for pattern Data.Maybe.Just i`

Comment: so your safeMaximum may not find a maximum for a non-empty list?

Comment: I don't understand; that example doesn't use `safeMaximum`.

Comment: `(\_ y -> sum y) :: (Num a) => t -> [a] -> a` but you said you want to use a function with safeMaximum semantics, of type `safeMaximum :: b -> [b] -> b`. that's different.

Comment: @Will I don't follow you; `(\_ y -> sum y)` can be typed as `b -> [b] -> b`.

Comment: can be, but isn't. it is indicative of the fact that it is more general. It isn't "picking" an element, but creating it.

Comment: @WillNess agreed, but I don't see the problem.  It fulfils `q`s type.  Isn't that okay?

Comment: that's why I assumed `Just i` pattern to be guaranteed, initially. If you're *picking* one elt of many, then it is guaranteed to be found among them.

Comment: Yeah, I was confused when I wrote the OP; I think it's kind of a dumb question ... sorry & thanks.

Comment: @MattFenwick: Quite the contrary, it seems reasonable at first that having a way to pick from a list should give you a way to pick from the same list plus extra information. Trying to write it and failing because it turns out it can't possibly work is, as you observed, an insightful lesson on why satisfying the demands of the type-checker is useful, not merely a chore.

Comment: @WillNess: By adding a type class constraint, yes, which is one of the key points here.

Comment: I don't understand what u r referring to w "new signature/interface"?

Comment: @C.A.McCann the initial absence of Ord constraint was by omission, not by design, on Matt's part.

Comment: @scvalex or thrice, if `f` traverses the list too. :) but efficiency wasn't the question, rather the possibility itself. Of course it can be improved with the usual zipping tricks and selecting `\`on\`` stuff etc.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe this is possible in a meaningful way.  Since this is just intuition, and I can't prove it, I'll just give a counterexample:

Let's say I have the function `sum :: Num a => [a] -> a`.  I can apply it to a list:

```
sum [1 .. 4]
> 10
```

But let's say I wanted to apply my 'lifted' `sum`:

```
liftedSum [("abc", 1), ("def", 2), ("ghi", 3), ("jkl", 4)]
> (??WTF??, 10)
```

What meaningful value should `??WTF??` have?  I can't think of one.

The problem was I interpreted `[b] -> b` as "pick one" when really, it can also mean "aggregate".  And there's no meaningful way to 'lift' an aggregate function into tuples, as I was trying to do.

But another problem is that, even if `[b] -> b` means "pick one", you can't use that to uniquely pick from `[(a, b)]`, if there are duplicate `b` values.  Example:

```
liftedMax [("abc", 1), ("def", 2), ("ghi", 2)]
> (>> is this "def" or "ghi"? <<, 2)
```

So I don't think that my function can be reasonably implemented, and I think it's cool that Haskell's type system made it hard for me to shoot myself in the foot.

Comment: you've showed supplying the default pair value yourself. I've updated my answer btw.

Comment: @WillNess your answer looks good; I didn't consider it in that light.

Answer (score 1):

Not with that exact type signature, no. 
For example, if you choose `type b = Double->Double` and your function `[b]->b` is `foldr (.) id`, 
then your polymorphic function `q` *cannot* use the value produced there to select from the pairs,
but I think that's misinterpreting your problem as seeking a specific type sig, rather than promoting/lifting
a means of selection from elements to pairs.

### Solving the raw selection problem

If your original function is used simply to select an element from a list, 
you could tell Haskell how to select between two, instead.

This solution is safe in the sense that it enforces using a selection from the original list or your fallback element,
by using a helper function `b -> b -> Bool`, where `True` indicates you prefer the first argument.

We can use that to select from a pair:

```
selectPair :: (a -> a -> Bool) -> (a,c) -> (a,c) -> (a,c)
selectPair f (a,c) (a',c') 
    | f a a'    = (a,c)
    | otherwise = (a',c')
```

And then fold to select from a list:

```
selectList :: (a -> a -> Bool) -> (a,c) -> [(a,c)] -> (a,c)
selectList f = foldr (selectPair f)
```

Notice that this doesn't require any instances on the type `a`, so might be what you need in a general setting.

### Solving the maximum problem

Of course `(b -> b -> Bool)` feels very like `>` from an `Ord` instance, and your example used 
a function suggesting maximum, but if you've got an Ord instance, 
it would would be simplest to use import `Data.List` and `Data.Function` to do

```
safePairMaximum :: Ord b => (a, b) -> [(a, b)] -> (a, b)
safePairMaximum m bs = maximumBy (compare `on` snd) $ m:bs
```

This is a more basic, less cool version of part of [hammar's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12748055/is-it-possible-to-implement-this-function/12749595#12749595).

### Maybe you're stuck-with [b]->b, but do have equality on b

This gets as close to your type signature as I think is sensible whilst still solving your stated problem:
If using a selection function `::[b]->b` is crucial, then you'll need at least an `Eq` context:

```
chooseLike :: Eq b => (a, b) -> ([b] -> b) -> ([(a, b)] -> (a, b))
chooseLike m selectb pairs = let wanted = selectb $ map snd pairs in
    case filter ((==wanted).snd) pairs of
      [] -> m
      (p:_) -> p
```

(You can of course replace the `Eq` context with a `(b -> b -> Bool)` argument, 
this time indicating equality.)

This isn't ideal, because you traverse the `[b]` list seperately to the `[(a,b)]` list, which seems inefficient.

### Conclusion

Although I believe there's no useful function of exactly the type you specify, 
there *are* various ways of solving the problem you stated. It was an interesting question, thanks.